# Crystal Reports 8 - 2 machines, only 1 exporting

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

i'm working on an old VB6 project, using CR 8. At the development machine, with Crystal Reports installed, i can export to excel, for example, without problems. Not so at a client machine. I've copied all the CRs dlls and used modules to compare what is different. The only thing different about the two machines is that the development is running XP SP2 and the client XP SP3. Some of the different dlls are advapi32.dll, mtxclu.dll, rpcrt4.dll, shlwapi.dll. I can open all the reports at the client machine, only export is failing. I can select the file type and select the destination. Just that progress box doesn't show up. Ah, the file is created with 0 bytes. Any clues?

Comment: Can you post the exact exception details?

Comment: I get no error at all, the only thing i notice is that the progress box doesn't show up

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Crystal files were copied into the System32 directory. That's where Crystal looks for them in Crystal 8/8.5.

Also make sure on your development machine, you're not using a custom DLL/call/function in a formula. If this DLL is not on the other machine, it won't work either.

Check and see if you have a \Crystal folder in your System32 directory on your development machine. If you do, and you have DLLs there, you might consider putting those on the non-working machine and registering the DLLs.